# Run exe from SQL agent Job cmdexec passing parameter todays date and date -52 weeks

Tags: sql-agent-job

I want to run a exe from SQL agent job using CMDEXEC. i want to pass parameter to the exe, which include todays date and date 52 weeks ago.

When i add below to command it runs successfully. But i want both the dates to be dynamic.

MY exe C:\abc.exe -fp "2017-08-16" -lp "2018-08-16"

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then write a small Powershell script which gives you the date and append them.

```
$date = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d"

$futureDate = (Get-Date).AddWeeks(52)
$futureDate = Get-Date $futureDate -Format -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d"
```

Then you can execute your exe file and use both variables. I haven't tested it yet it's only a short idea.